# How to run algorithms in ns2 nodes?

Tags: ns2

I am working with ns-2, and i would like to know whether it is possible to run an algorithm within a node to select the next node. If it is possible kindly guide me through the steps for doing so. If this is not possible please tell me a simulator where i can do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ns2 simulator.. it has some default protocol like aodv, dsdv and dsr each one has separate algorithm to choose next hop node. you can find some examples (ns2.xx/tcl/ex) in installed Ns2-all-in one package.